# Markov chain on a subset of state space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

**Problem :** Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be an irreducible Markov chain on $I$ having an invariant distribution $\pi$ . For $J \subseteq I$ let  $(Y_m)_{m\ge 0}$ be a Markov chain such that $Y_m = X_{T_m}$ where
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
T_0 = \inf\{n\ge 0 : X_n \in J\} \\
T_{m+1} = \inf \{ n > T_m : X_n \in J \},  & m =0,1,...
\end{array}\right.
$$
and we assume $P(T_m< \infty) = 1 $ for all $m$ . **Show that  $(Y_m)_{m\ge 0}$  is positive recurrent and find its invariant distribution .**

**Question :** I'd like to have a solution verification or alternative approaches .

(Problem's from exercise 1.10.3 of Markov Chains by J.R. Norris)

---

**Attempt :**

**Positive recurrent :** Since $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is irreducible on $I$ , it must also be irreducible on $J\subseteq I$ . Let transition probability of $(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be $\bar{p}$ , we have
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^n \bar{p}_{j_0j_1}^k \ge p_{j_0j_1}^n > 0 , \quad  j_0,j_1\in J , \exists n
$$
it follows that $\bar{p}_{j_0j_1}^k > 0 , \exists k$ . We've just shown $(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is irreducible , so [1] guarantees that the chain is positive recurrent .

**Auxiliary MC :** Consider a Markov chain $(Z_n)_{n\ge 0}$ where
$$
Z_n = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
z_1 & \text{ if $X_n\in I\setminus J $ } \\
z_2 & \text{ if $X_n\in J $ }
\end{array}\right.
$$
The transition probabilities are
$$
\hat{p}_{z_1z_2} = \sum_{i\in I \setminus J , j\in J} \frac{1}{|I| - |J|} p_{ij} , \quad 
\hat{p}_{z_2z_1} = \sum_{i\in I \setminus J , j\in J} \frac{1}{|J|} p_{ji} 
$$
and $\hat{p}_{z_1z_1} = 1 - \hat{p}_{z_1z_2} , \hat{p}_{z_2z_2} = 1 - \hat{p}_{z_2z_1}$ .
$(Z_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is irreducible due to irreducibility of $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ . Its invariant distribution $\hat{\pi}$ is
$$
\hat{\pi}_{z_1} = \frac{\hat{p}_{z_1z_2}}{\hat{p}_{z_1z_2} + \hat{p}_{z_2z_1}} , \quad
\hat{\pi}_{z_2} = \frac{\hat{p}_{z_2z_1}}{\hat{p}_{z_1z_2} + \hat{p}_{z_2z_1}} 
$$

**Invariant distribution :** [2] guarantees the existence of invariant distribution of $(Y_n)_{n\ge 0}$ ,  $\bar{\pi}$ . Consider for $j_0\in J$ , by [3]
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{V_{j_0}(n)}{\sum_{j\in J} V_j(n) } 
= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{V_{j_0}(n)}{n} \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\sum_{j\in J} V_j(n) }
\overset{a.s.}\longrightarrow \frac{\pi_{j_0}}{\hat{\pi}_{z_2}}
= \bar{\pi}_{j_0} 
$$

---

[1] David and Yuval . Markov Chains & Mixing Times , p. 10 , Lemma 1.13 .

> Lemma 1.13. For any states $x$ and $y$ of an irreducible chain , $E_x(\tau_y^+) < \infty$ . 
> where $E_x(\cdot)$ is the expectation conditioned on the MC $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ starting at state $x$ , $\tau_x^+ := \min\{t\ge 1 : X_t = x\}$

[2] J.R. Norris . Markov Chains , p.37 , Theorem 1.7.7 .

> Theorem 1.7.7 Let $P$ be irreducible . Then the following are equivalent : 
> (i) every state is positive recurrent ;
> (ii) some state $i$ is positive recurrent ; 
> (iii) $P$ has an invariant distribution , $\pi$ say . 
> Moreover , when (iii) holds we have expected return time $m_i = 1/\pi_i$ for all $i$ .

[3] J.R. Norris . Markov Chains , p.53 , Theorem 1.10.2 .

> Theorem 1.10.2  Let $P$ be irreducible and let $\lambda$ be any distribution . If $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is Markov$(\lambda,P)$ then
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left( \frac{V_i(n)}{n} \to \frac{1}{m_i} \text{ as } n \to \infty  \right) = 1 
> $$
> where $V_i(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{X_k = i\}}$ and $m_i$ is expected return time to state $i$ .